# How to find out the url of a popup?

Tags: sitemap

I'm creating a Sitemap by hand.

I want to add in the url of a popup -- I presume it has a url.

At the top of this page: http://wordfruit.com -- there's a yellow-highlighted link with the text 'How does it work?'

Is there a url of that popup? How do I determine what that url is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a pop up. That content already on the page as a hidden div. Then javascript is used to present it. So there is no need to submit it in the XML sitemap since it is indexed when that page is indexed.